# WebClient.UploadValuesAsync - Get values sent in request

Tags: c#, webclient

Once a `UploadValuesCompleted` Event has fired, is it possible to get the `NameValueCollection` that was uploaded in the request?

I want the possibility to resend a duplicate of a request.

I am doing something like this:

```
NameValueCollection data = new NameValueCollection();
data.Add("myParam", "myValue");

WC.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
WC.UploadValuesAsync(Url, "POST", data);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your event handler can access `data` if you pass data to it, for example by using closure semantics or an instance variable.

It could look like this:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
var data = GetPostData();
client.UploadValuesCompleted += (sender, e) => { Console.WriteLine(data); };
UploadValuesAsync("url", "POST", data);
```

The event handler now has access to `data`.

Comment: Are you referring to the original question concerning the `WebClient`, or my answer which showed my extension `APIRequest`? If the latter then this is what I did.

Comment: Referring to the original question. Trying to generalize your answer because inheritance is not needed.

Comment: OK, can you post some example code please. I'm not sure I understand your answer.

Comment: Thanks, I get it now. You're right, much easier than inheritance.

Comment: I think you missed a semicolon on line 3

Comment: @XStylish fixed.

Answer (score 1):

To do this I have extended the `WebClient` to give both the request Url and the Values sent.

```
class APIRequest : WebClient
{

    public Uri Url { get; private set; }
    public NameValueCollection Data { get; private set; }

    public void sendRequest(Uri url, NameValueCollection data)
    {
        Url = url;
        Data = data;

        Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        UploadValuesAsync(url, "POST", data);
    }

}
```

It also required that I made changes to my other code, I was previously using a single WebClient for many requests, now I'm using one for each.